# header background color changed after drop & import database in phpmyadmin

Tags: css, sql, headers, phpmyadmin

This is what I did in phpmyadmin.

1. Export DB in .sql format
2. Drop all tables
3. Import the exported DB

The database should be same, but the website looks weird as below... how come...?

Before (black header)

[image: Before]

After (white header)
[image: After]

Comment: seems like i need to recreate & re-customize everything, sad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

Login wordpress admin panel, go to the theme click 'Save Change' then the layout/header/word color returned to normal. But I don't understand why like this...

Answer (score 0):

In general, things that are not content, better not be in the DB in the first place. Site header images should be in you CSS, making them part of your code which you manage with GIT.

This is obviously easier said than done with the way wordpress core and many plugins geared towards storing everything possible in the DB, but some things are just a "no brainer" and clearly should go into code. Even horrible plugins (from the POV of abusing DB as a replacement for proper coding) like ACF, let you now declare DB structure as json files you can manage as code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are trying to accomplish. You normally don't want to mess with WP's database without a very thorough knowledge of how the db works. Lots of inter-relationships of the data. If you are trying to 'style' the output/page, then you need to learn how to build themes, or to make a Child Theme and modify pieces of the theme.

Comment: Yes really, just a simple export(backup db), drop(empty db), import(restore db), then the header/footer color changed. Compared the db code some id, code position changed. Weird...